# UPDATE statement while loading data

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following scenario: I run an update statement on 10M rows table, to update a certain status flag. While the statement is still running, new data have been ingested to the table. The question is: will this new data be affected by the update, or only the initial 10M is considered ?

Comment: It depends on the [isolation level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-transaction-isolation-level-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). If you use NOLOCK or READ UNCOMMITTED (both bad ideas), the new records will be visible. What do *you* want to do? How do you intend to modify 10M rows?

Comment: On the other hand, updating every row in a table will escalate locks to the table level and *prevent* other rows from inserting while the mass update takes place. If you try to perform the update in batches, changes between batches will be visible if you use the READ COMMITTED isolation level

Comment: both are not used (NOLOCK or READ UNCOMMITTED) so I guess the new records won't be visible. The modification is just setting a column [Status] = 1

Comment: That's not a `just`, if the column is a `bit` updating it could lock the entire table - it makes no sense to create an index over a `bit` field as 50% of the rows will have one value and the other 50% another. So the server will perform a full table scan, locking the entire table. This can block INSERTs for as long as the UPDATE runs - or delay the UPDATE until all INSERTs are finished. In either case, it's *slooow* and can freeze the system. What are the chances that no other row in 10M will be modified?

Comment: You could use SNAPSHOT isolation to avoid blocking other transactions. With snapshot isolation, the server maintains the original state of modified rows so each transaction sees the data as it was when it started, but readers don't block writers and vice versa. Blocking occurs only if two transactions try to modify the same row. Interim versions are stored in tempdb, so if you need to modify *all* rows, you may end up with 10M temporary rows stored in tempdb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**update** -> first selects rows to be affected, locks them to prevent any change, then updates those rows.

you can insert new rows without problems (if there is no constraint violation :)).

Any row that is inserted after the UPDATE will not be seen by the UPDATE statement and thus they won't be changed.

Comment: This depends on the isolation level. If someone uses NOLOCK, new rows will be visible

Comment: Updating every row in a table will escalate locking to the table level too

Comment: In other words... it's far more complicated than the accepted answer says it is

Comment: sure but, I believe that mine covers what OP is after. Sure there is 10000+ words documents about locking.

Comment: what @PanagiotisKanavos has provided was indeed informative, and surely will be considered in production scenarios. For my test case, it was sufficient for me know whether the new records are visible to the UPDATE or not.

Comment: @khidir you'll run into those issues a lot sooner than you think. As soon as you realize that updating a 10M table takes forever and freezes the system, you'll try using a cursor or batching the updates. If you wanted to use a table as a queue, things become a *lot* more complicated and simple locking won't be enough

Comment: I cannot agree more with the last comment